# POST Request in Body as x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-headers

I used the below code to POST `grant_type` , `client_id` , `client_secret` , `refresh token` to `https://webexapis.com/v1/access_token`
Below is the postman Javascript-fetch console which is successful when I try in POstman

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
urlencoded.append("client_id", "xxxx");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "yyyy");
urlencoded.append("refresh_token", "zzzz");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://webexapis.com/v1/access_token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Kindly help me to get the result in Appscript.
So I tried the below code in the Google Sheets script, but it's showing error

```
function webexDev() {
    
var cisurl = "https://webexapis.com/v1/access_token";

var data = {
  'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
  'client_id': 'xxxx',
  'client_secret': 'yyyy',
  'refresh_token': 'zzzz'
};

var options = { 'method': 'post', 'payload': data, 'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cisurl,options);
    var cisjson=response.getContentText();
    var cisdata=JSON.parse(cisjson)
   Logger.log(cisjson)
}
```

I tried the same in Postman and it got successful. I want to the same in Google Sheet Script
[image]

Comment: Instead of (or as well as) looking at the user interface in Postman, look at the actual request generated by Postman, when you hit "Send". Then you will see how the data in the screenshot is converted into a valid request. Use _that_ as your guide for what you need to build in your script..

Comment: Also: `"x-www-form-urlencoder"` appears to have a typo in it (it ends with a `d` not `r`. And it's a part of a content type (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)). It's also the _default_ content type for form data. See the "Headers" tab in Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing things up. Those parameters grant_type, client_id, client_secret and refresh_token are not HTTP-Headers but the payload that you're sending to the server.

According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), this should work:

```
var cisurl = "https://webexapis.com/v1/access_token";

var data = {
  'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
  'client_id': 'abcdefg',
  'client_secret': 'hijklmn',
  'refresh_token': 'opqrstuvw'
};

var options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'payload': data
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cisurl,options);
```

**P.S.: Do not share your secrets on stack-overflow**

Comment: `function webexDevice() {
    
var cisurl = "https://webexapis.com/v1/access_token";

var data = {
  'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
  'client_id': 'xxxx',
  'client_secret': 'yyyy',
  'refresh_token': 'S00MjVm'
};

var options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'payload': data
}

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cisurl,options);
    var cisjson=response.getContentText();
    var cisdata=JSON.parse(cisjson)
   Logger.log(cisjson)
   `

Comment: I am getting error as `Exception: Request failed for https://webexapis.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"message":"POST failed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request (url = https://idbroker.webex.com/idb/oauth2/v1/access_token, request/response TrackingId = ROUTE... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`

Comment: Ok maybe you will have to set the contentType explicitly:
Could you try it with "contentType": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' within the options?

Comment: It's showin error for the line
var options = { 'method': 'post', 'payload': data 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

Is this right

Comment: You're. missing the contentType:
{ 'method': 'post', 'payload': data, 'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

Comment: I am sorry, I am getting the same error. I tried - var options = { 'method': 'post', 'payload': data, 'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

Comment: What kind of error is it? It should be correct syntactically?

Comment: @Moses - you can [edit] your question to show the raw text representation of the successful request (headers and body) generated by Postman. Click on the "terminal" icon in the bottom left hand side of the Postman app.

Comment: @Moses - And remember to **always** hide/obfuscate your key data.  And you need to delete & disable the key data that you have shown in your question, since it is now public.

Comment: Hello @andrewjames
I edited the question with the postman console Javascript-fetch
Please check

Comment: Hello @Andreas.Ludwig
I edited my question, this is the console of Postman where I get successful Output

Comment: @Moses - I am not sure about your edits: (1) What happened to your `UrlFetchApp` code? It has gone from the question. (2) Where is the raw text representation of the successful request (headers and body) generated by Postman? I think you have overwritten your question, instead of adding clarifications to it. The code we now see in your question is not the code you are having problems with. It's something completely different.

Comment: @andrewjames I added the old code in question, Please now compare with postman code and our appscript code.

Comment: My apologies @Andreas.Ludwig - my request for clarification may have made it harder for you to provide an answer. I was hoping to see the raw request data. Maybe the additional code helps?